# XdbModelConflictException when working with two model builders

Tags: xconnect

I have two foundational projects that each build out an xConnect model. However, whenever I deploy them both I get the error.

```
2719 Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XdbModelConflictException
2722 Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
2723    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
```

one has code and config that looks like this.

```
<xconnect>
      <runtime
        type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
          <schema name="documentationmodel"
                  type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration"
                  patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
            <param desc="modeltype">MyNamespace.Models.CollectionModel, MyNamespace.UserSettings</param>
          </schema>
        </schemas>
      </runtime>
    </xconnect>
```

```
public class CollectionModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("DocumentationModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, MyClass>(FacetNames.MyFacetName);

            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }
```

This is what the other one looks like:

```
<xconnect>
      <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
           <!--value of 'name' property must be unique--> 
          <schema name="ContactModel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" 
                  patch:before="schema[@name='customDataModel']">
            <param desc="modeltype">MyNamespace.XConnect.Facets.ContactModel, MyNamespace.XConnect</param>
          </schema>
        </schemas>
      </runtime>
    </xconnect>
```

```
public class ContactModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("MyNamespace.XConnect.Facets.ContactModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, FacetName>(Keys.DefaultFacetKey);

            modelBuilder.DefineEventType<Events.MyEvent>(false);

            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }
```

I have been tinkering for a while and cannot find any rhyme or reason why they will not work together.

Comment: Did you forgot to add reference `modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);` in `CollectionModel` before facet definition?

Comment: Also check that xconnect schemas in `showconfig.aspx` are not duplicated and all of them have unique names. And check that json models in `xconnect\App_Data\Models\` deployed once and do not duplicated too.

Comment: Are you allowed to have an Event model and a contact model together? I think Events only go with Interaction models
            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, FacetName>(Keys.DefaultFacetKey);

            modelBuilder.DefineEventType<Events.MyEvent>(false);